# Dividing by two for NaturalNumbers using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I do not understand the point of this line of code

```java
if (tens %2!= 0)
{ 
  ones += 10;
}
```

Recursion is finding a small problem inside a big one. But, I do not understand how this code implements this behavior. Can you explain how to approach the problem systematically?

**Used methods:**

```java
void multiplyBy10(int k)
```

**multiplies this by 10 and adds k**

```java
int divideBy10()
```

**divides this by 10 and reports the remainder**

The whole code:

```java
private static void divideBy2(NaturalNumber n) {
    int ones, tens;

    if (!n.isZero()) {
        ones = n.divideBy10();
        tens = n.divideBy10();
        if (tens % 2 != 0) {
            ones += 10;
        }
        ones = ones / 2;
        n.multiplyBy10(tens);
        divideBy2(n);
        n.multiplyBy10(ones);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]? Include the code for class `NaturalNumber`. Indicate what result you expect when you call method `divideBy2`.

Comment: we need definition `n.multiplyBy10(tens); and n.divideBy10();` -- how it behaves!! ? you are calling two times n.divideBy10(); -- which makes n (when n = 21) 0.